# How to caught the number of row affected by an INSERT in MonetDB?

Tags: database, rows, monetdb

hen using the user-interface `mclient` it's quite useful to see the number of rows affected by your `INSERT` query.

```
sql>INSERT INTO ..... 
125 affected rows (832.608ms)
```

I wonder if there is a way to obtain this information within a SQL program in MonetDB like `Oracle` does with `SQL%ROWCOUNT` in PG/SQL?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

MONETDB has an ODBC and JDBC driver and both these provide the rows affected if you use the GUI client or even a script written in PHP/Python/Java